# O que pode mudar com a implementação do variadic function?

Tags: php, funções

O PHP 5.6 implementou uma funcionalidade chamada [Variadic function](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list).

É como se fossem argumentos infinitos. Eles podem ser usados tanto na **declaração de uma função** como para o chamamento.

## Exemplos PHP 5.6

Exemplo na declaração:

```
function test($arg, ...$args)
{
    print_r($args);
}

test('first argument', 1, 2, 3); // imprime: array(1, 2, 3);
```

Exemplo no chamamento:

```
function test($first_name, $last_name)
{
    return "{$first_name} {$last_name}";
}

$args =  ['Wallace', 'Maxters'];

$alias = 'test';

$alias(...$args); // Wallace Maxters

test(...$args); // Wallace Maxters
```

## Exemplos versões anteriores a 5.6

Esses exemplos se fossem utilizados em versões anteriores a `5.6`, poderiam ser feitos da seguinte forma:

Exemplo declaração:

```
function test($arg)
{
    $args = array_slice(func_get_args(), 1);
    
    print_r($args);
}

test('first argument', 1, 2, 3); // array(1, 2, 3)
```

Exemplo chamamento:

```
function test($first_name, $last_name)
{
    return "{$first_name} {$last_name}";
}

$args = ['Wallace', 'Maxters'];

$alias = 'test';

echo call_user_func_array($alias, $args); // Wallace Maxters
echo call_user_func_array('test', $args); // Wallace Maxters
```

Depois da implementação do `variadic function`, para quem usar o PHP 5.6, qual vai ser a finalidade das funções `call_user_func_array` e `func_get_args`?

Essa implementação do `variadic function` pode comprometer essas funções e, futuramente, torná-las obsoletas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu não acompanho de perto os desenvolvimentos do PHP, mas o pouco que vejo passa a impressão de que eles são bastante conservadores, e que mesmo quando algo é marcado como obsoleto (*deprecated*) ainda pode levar um bom tempo para ser de fato removido. Concordo com o @gmsantos nesse ponto, o PHP evita ao máximo criar incompatibilidades com códigos legados.

Quanto às duas funções citadas, o `func_get_args` eu acredito que seja mantido, pois tem uma função diferente do parâmetro *splat* das funções variádicas, já que retorna **todos** os argumentos recebidos. O `call_user_func_array` também tem seu papel, pois permite a passagem de argumentos dinâmicos mesmo que a função não seja variádica. Isso sem dizer que permite ainda chamar uma função pelo nome (como string), como o `call_user_func`. Em resumo, vejo motivos para as duas funções serem mantidas, principalmente `func_get_args`.

Answer (score 1):

Ao meu ver as `variadic function` irão substituir `call_user_func_array` e `func_get_args`.

Elas ficariam ali por alguns releases para manter a compatibilidade com códigos que precisem funcionar em versões anteriores do PHP 5.6 até que um belo dia [entrem em votação para serem descontinuadas](https://wiki.php.net/rfc).

Não espere que isso seja feito em breve. As últimas versões incluíram sintaxe alternativa para outras coisas, como a [sintaxe de array no PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration54.new-features.php), que substitui a função [`array()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array.php) e o [operador de potenciação também no PHP 5.6](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.exponentiation) que faz a mesma coisa que a função [`pow()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.pow.php). Ambos os casos continuam valendo até que seja decidido que não vale mais a pena mantê-los ali, como aconteceu [várias coisas](https://wiki.php.net/start?id=deprecated&do=search) (exemplo da extensão [`mysql_*`](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation)).

Answer (score 0):

Apenas como complemento às respostas anteriores:
um simples exemplo é o de melhoria da sintaxe e a diminuição da chamada de funções, melhorando o desempenho.

Antigamente:

```
call_user_function_array(array($controller, $method), $parameters);
```

Atualmente:

```
$controller->$method(...$parameters);
```

Outra vantagem pode ser vista na declaração de métodos ou funções. Vou dar um exemplo que sempre utilizo, que é a utilização de um método estático pra facilitar a criação da instância da classe.

Antigamente:

```
 class Controller {

    public function __construct(Request $request, Response $response)
    {

    }

    public static function make(Request $request, Response $response)
    {
         return new static($request, $respone);
    }

}
```

Atualmente:

```
class Controller {

    public function __construct(Request $request, Response $response)
    {

    }
    /** Não precisa declarar as mesmas coisas de construct, é um atalho **/
    public static function make(...$arguments)
    {
         return new static(...$arguments);
    }

}


Controller::make(new Request, new Response);
```

Comment: Concordo que são vantagens. Mas isso responde ao que foi perguntado (por você mesmo)?

Comment: @bfavaretto, foi apenas um detalhe adicional que acho que poderia ter sido colocado em alguma das questões.

Comment: Talvez isso caiba na própria pergunta.