# Qual é o nome do operador ... usado no PHP 5.6?

Tags: php, operadores, php-7

A partir do `PHP 5.6` temos agora a possibilidade de invocar ou declarar uma função, informando que os argumentos são infinitos, através do operador `...`.

Exemplo:

```
function add(... $arguments)
{
    return array_sum($arguments);
}

add(1, 2, 3); // imprime: 6
```

Exemplo 2:

```
print_r(...[$object, false]);
// é equivalente a:
print_r($object, false);
```

Fiz uma pergunta relacionada às [variadic functions](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52344/o-que-pode-mudar-com-a-implementa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-variadic-function) onde é explicadas as vantagens do seu uso.

Porém eu não sei o nome desse operador usado no `variadic funcion`, o tal do operador `...`.

Costumo falar reticencias. Mas não sei se estou certo.

Qual é o nome correto desse operador?

Comment: Operador **Descompactador**.

Comment: @DiegoSouza, descompactador não seria no ato da chamada? Ele também pode ser usado na declaração da função (o que o tornaria um compactador, ao meu ver).

Comment: Sim. Eu que dei esse nome agora.

Comment: ja não dava pra fazer isso com `func_get_args`? PHP, simplesmente PHP

Comment: Como o @rray disse, o PHP está trocando `funções` por `operadores`. E dá um trabalho maior usando `func_get_args`.  Na pergunta [o que vai mudar com variadic function](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52344/o-que-pode-mudar-com-a-implementa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-variadic-function) explica os ganhos.

Comment: Um exemplo disso pode ser comparando os códigos de frameworks. Ao invés de usar `call_user_func_array(array($controller, $method), $arguments`, poderia ser usado assim `$controller->$method(...$arguments)`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## [*Splat*](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2014/php-5-6-and-the-splat-operator) (ou ainda, [*Scatter*, ou *Spread*](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/argument_unpacking)).

Ele é um operador para indicar que sua função pode ter um número qualquer de parâmetros. Este nome é específico do PHP. Em outras linguagens, o nome muda.

Se sua função tem *splat* na declaração e possui mais de um argumento, o *splat* deve ser necessariamente o último argumento.

Comment: Interassante. Acho que no `python` seria utilizado um asterísco. `*args`.

Comment: Sim, um ou dois asteriscos. Tem as duas versões.

Comment: Se lerem o manual do PHP em inglês podem ver que isto está errado: "Arrays and Traversable objects can be unpacked into argument lists when calling functions by using the ... operator. This is also known as the splat operator in other languages, including Ruby. " splat é o nome em ruby.

Comment: Dois asteriscos seriam para `kwargs`. No caso do PHP (comparando com o `python`), seria o `*args`. Pois é um list. E no PHP `...` só funciona em `arrays` com índices numéricos.

Comment: Não estou falando de `python` só pra agradar :D

Comment: @BlunT Não tem nada de errado não. [O termo é bem aceito pelos colaboradores](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/argument_unpacking). Tem até mais um, o tal de "spread".

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez realmente nunca tinha ouvido esse termo, apenas variadic. mas errado é forte demais, tens razão.

Comment: Acho que ele é chamado de `ellipses` também, @CiganoMorrisonMendez.

Comment: Este eu não conhecia.

Answer (score 3):

Esse tipo de parâmetro é baseado num tipo similar existente no C++ há bastante tempo.

O nome desse tipo de parametro em C++ é mesmo `variadic arguments`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments

Nem a microsoft traduz o nome variadic, por isso o termo é mesmo utilizado assim: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dn439779.aspx

Comment: +1 . Bem, acho que estou aprendendo bastante o nome dos operadores aqui no SOPT :)

Answer (score -1):

Complementando a resposta, o Spread Operator (ou Unpacking Operator, dependendo do contexto de sua aplicação) pode ter um comportamento diferente no caso de sua utilização em arrays, adotando um comportamento semelhante ao func_get_args(), conforme exemplos a seguir:

Spreading:

```
$args1 = [1, 2, 3];
$args2 = [4, 5, 6];
test(...$args1, ...$args2); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
test(1, 2, 3, ...$args2);   // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Unpacking:

```
$arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
$arr2 = [...$arr1]; //[1, 2, 3]
$arr3 = [0, ...$arr1]; //[0, 1, 2, 3]
$arr4 = array(...$arr1, ...$arr2, 111); //[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 111]
$arr5 = [...$arr1, ...$arr1]; //[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
 
function getArr() {
  return ['a', 'b'];
}
$arr6 = [...getArr(), 'c']; //['a', 'b', 'c']
 
$arr7 = [...new ArrayIterator(['a', 'b', 'c'])]; //['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Para maiores informações, vide documentação: [Spread Operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/spread_operator_for_array) e [Unpacking](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/argument_unpacking) (uso em arrays)