# Como inserir os elementos do array X num índice do array Y?

Tags: php, array

Possuo o array `y` onde no seu índice `0` possui os valores `App` e `Views`

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'App' (length=3)
      1 => string 'Views' (length=5)
```

No `x` eu tenho um `array` com `N` valores

```
array (size=1)
      0 => 'a'
      1 => 'b'
      ...
```

E quero agregá-los ao primeiro índice do `array` `x`, ao utilizar `array_merge` não obtenho o resultado esperado:

```
array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'App' (length=3)
          1 => string 'Views' (length=5)
      1 => 'a'
      2 => 'b'
```

Quando deveria ser:

```
array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'App' (length=3)
          1 => string 'Views' (length=5)
          2 => string 'a'
...
```

Exemplo:

```
$ranking[] = ['App', 'Views'];

$options[] = ['A', 'B'];

$merge = array_merge($ranking, $options);
$merge2 = array_merge($ranking[0], $options);

var_dump($merge);
var_dump($merge2);
```

Exemplo no [ideone](http://ideone.com/PemAk7)

Comment: Coloca o código do ideone na pergunta :)

Comment: Seria algo assim? https://ideone.com/IWahLp

Comment: @rray Ops! Editado!

Comment: Aparentemente sim, @RafaelWithoeft

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você deve deve selecionar o array adequado (posição 0 do array y) pra fazer o merge:

```
$y[0] = array_merge($y[0],$x);
```

Answer (score 3):

Com o PHP5.6 pode simplificar essa atribuição, combinando [`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) e o operador [eclipse(`...`)](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list), ele desempacota cada elemento do array como um argumento para `push_array()`, na prática a instrução gerada seria algo como `array_push($ranking[0], 'A', 'B', 'C')`

[Exemplo - ideone](https://ideone.com/hKGSpl)

```
<?php
   $ranking[] = ['App', 'Views'];
   $options[] = ['A', 'B'];
   array_push($ranking[0], ...$options[0]);

   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($ranking);
```

Saida:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => App
            [1] => Views
            [2] => A
            [3] => B
        )

)
```

**Relacionado:**

[Qual é o nome do operador … usado no PHP 5.6?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87234/91)