# Somar valores de um mesmo array PHP

Tags: php, array, soma

Parece ser simples mas não consegui, gostaria de somar o seguinte array (são dois arrays dentro de um, ele é dividido com o array_chunk):

```
    $arr = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
];
```

gostaria que o resultado fosse esse:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 7   // 1+6
    [1] => 9   // 2+7
    [2] => 11  // 3+8
    [3] => 13  // 4+9
    [4] => 5   // 5+0
)
```

agradeço desde já;

Comment: Agora descreva, por favor, o que aconteceu para o primeiro virar o segundo.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem nem o problema nem a dúvida

Comment: agradeço as respostas, são dois array dentro de um, gostaria de somar os dois para se tornar somente um, consegui com a função que marquei como resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agradeço a ajuda de todos, consegui com o seguinte código:

```
    $soma_array = array();

foreach ($producao_ as $k=>$subArray) {
  foreach ($subArray as $id=>$v) {
    $soma_array[$id]+=$v;
  }
}

print_r($soma_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Se a ideia é somar os elementos dos *array* internos elemento a elemento, então basta fazer:

```
$result = array_map(function(...$values) {
  return array_sum($values);
}, ...$arr);
```

Assim, ao ter o *array*:

```
$arr = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
];
```

O resultado será:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 7   // 1+6
    [1] => 9   // 2+7
    [2] => 11  // 3+8
    [3] => 13  // 4+9
    [4] => 5   // 5+0
)
```

Inclusive funciona para qualquer quantidade de *arrays*:

```
$arr = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
  [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
  [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
];

$result = array_map(function(...$values) {
  return array_sum($values);
}, ...$arr);

print_r($result);

// Array
// (
//     [0] => 17
//     [1] => 23
//     [2] => 29
//     [3] => 35
//     [4] => 31
// )
```

- [Qual é o nome do operador ... usado no PHP 5.6?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87234/5878)
- [Documentação da função `array_map`](http://php.net/array_map)
- [Documentação da função `array_sum`](http://php.net/array_sum)