# Erro ao passar variável como parâmetro duplo

Tags: php, parâmetros

Tenho uma função

```
pesquisaPagamentos($pesquisa)
```

Tenho uma variável `$pesquisa` que esta recebendo o seguinte valor: `'2015-10-05','2015-10-01'`, com as aspas simples.

Acontece que da forma que esta, quando chega na função

```
<?php 
  if(isset($_GET["acao"]) && $_GET["acao"] == "listaArr") {

      $pesquisa = (isset($_POST["dataIni"])) ? "'".$PhpUtil->formataData($_POST["dataFim"])."','".$PhpUtil->formataData($_POST["dataIni"])."'" : "'',''";



print "<pre>";                                  
print_r($pesquisa);                                 
print "</pre>";                                 

      $arrecadacaoDia = $rel->pesquisaPagamentos($pesquisa);
```

Tento imprimir o valor do primeiro parâmetro e vem o valor inteiro da variável $pesquisa, ou seja: `'2015-10-05','2015-10-01'`. Já o segundo parâmetro da função recebe valor vazio.

Comment: Faça separado: $pesquisa_data_inicio = "2015-01-02"; $pesquisa_data_final = "2015-02-02"; pesquisaPagamentos($pesquisa_data_inicio, $pesquisa_data_final)

Comment: Mas na chamada vc passou o segundo argumento? no exemplo da pergunta não.

Comment: Veja: se '2015-10-05','2015-10-01'. note que existe uma virgula no meio. Isso não é o suficiente para que a variável popule os 2 parâmetros quando impressa?

Comment: Essa é chamada da função? `$rel->pesquisaPagamentos($pesquisa);`? só tem um argumento, precisa de dois

Comment: a função pede 2 argumentos, porém, a saída do valor da variável $pesquisa, emula uma string do tipo 'valor1', 'valor2' mas acabei fazendo conforme tua orientação. Ficou mais legivel! Obrigado!

Answer (score 4):

Para receber dois ou mais argumentos em função é necessário mudar primeiro sua assinatura.

```
function pesquisaPagamentos($pesquisa){
```

para

```
function pesquisaPagamentos($datainicio, $datafim){
```

A chamada deve ser feita dessa forma

```
pesquisaPagamentos('2015-09-01', '2015-10-05');
pesquisaPagamentos($data1, $data2);
```

Não adianta passar um string seperada por virgula, a função vai entender que isso é apenas um argumento.

Chamada inválido

```
pesquisaPagamentos('2015-09-01,2015-10-05');
```

Também é possível ter dois parâmetros e passar somente um valor para função, desde que o segundo parâmetro tenha um valor padrão.

```
function pesquisaPagamentos($datainicio, $datafim='2015-12-31'){
```

Chamada:

```
pesquisaPagamentos('2015-09-01');
```

A partir do php5.6 existe um operador `...` que define multiplos parâmetros para uma função ele faz basicamente o que [func_get_args](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)

[Exemplo - ideone](https://ideone.com/tMZsWZ)

**Leitura recomendada:**

[Qual a diferença entre parâmetro e argumento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/91)

[Qual é o nome do operador … usado no PHP 5.6?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87234/91)

[O que pode mudar com a implementação do variadic function?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52344/91)

Comment: Obrigado! Era isso que eu gostaria de evitar. Mas acabou que tive que fazer assim mesmo!

Answer (score 3):

Faça separado:

```
$pesquisa_data_inicio = "2015-01-02"; 
$pesquisa_data_final = "2015-02-02"; 
pesquisaPagamentos($pesquisa_data_inicio, $pesquisa_data_final)
```