# Em C# existe variadic arguments (argumentos infinitos)?

Tags: c#, característica-linguagem

Em linguagens como *PHP 5.6* e *Python*, é possível definir "argumentos infinitos", (em PHP é chamado de [variadic args](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52344/o-que-pode-mudar-com-a-implementa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-variadic-function)) numa função/método.

Por exemplo, é possível definir uma função assim em PHP 5.6:

```
 function variadic($name, ...$args) {

      echo $name;

      foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
          echo $value;
      }
 }

 variadic('name', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
```

Ou seja, do segundo argumento em diante, podemos passar argumentos "infinitos" para a função.

Existe alguma forma de fazer isso em C#? É vantajoso em algum caso?

E se existir, como é a nomeclatura em C#?

Comment: Também tem http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-arg.php em php. Assim até escusa de 'forçar' algum argumento

Comment: Eu citei isso na pergunta :p

Comment: Opps não vi que se referia a este método

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize o modificador [params](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/w5zay9db.aspx):

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static void UseParams(params int[] list)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(list[i] + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Observação: Esse modificador tem que ser usado sozinho, ou se tiver mais parâmetros ser sempre o último.

***Exemplo:***

*Forma correta:*

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static void UseParams(string c, string d, params int[] list)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(list[i] + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

*Forma Errada: Causa erros e não compila*

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static void UseParams(params int[] list, string d)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(list[i] + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

***Resposta:*** [SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7580295/6402423)

***Referencia:*** https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/w5zay9db.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Sim, existe. Exemplo:

```
string.Format(string format, params object[] args);
```

Consumo:

```
string.Format("Meu nome é {0}, eu tenho {1} anos", "Caffé", 36);
```

A diferença é que em C# a tipagem é estática.

É vantajoso nos casos quando você quer admitir qualquer quantidade de um mesmo tipo de argumento no seu método.

Veja, antes de existir este tipo de argumento declarado com a palavra chave *params*, um método como o *string.Format* precisaria de várias sobrecargas (overloads) para permitir variadas quantidades de parâmetros, ou exigiria que você criasse explicitamente um array para passar por parâmetro.